# Filtering out objects from ArrayList<Object> based on object field?

Tags: android

I am looking for a simple method instead of `while`/`for` loop, for filtering out set of objects from `ArrayList<Object>` base on the object that contains a unique value.

For example ,i have list of object as

```
[Status [status=new], Status [status=closed], Status [status=new], Status [status=closed], Status [status=new], Status [status=closed], Status [status=new], Status [status=closed], Status [status=new], Status [status=closed]].
```

I need the objects that has status value`"new"` into a list to compare.No need of the object that has already `closed`.

Comment: Post some code of what you have done. And explain yourself better, please.

Comment: use Set<> instead of ArrayList

Answer (score 4):

The unique way to write less and readable code for filtering a collection is use *java 8 lambda expressions*.

Unfortunately java8 is not still supported by Android but....you can use [**retrolambda**](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda).
And if you need to use the Stream API you can try this plugin [**Lightweight-Stream-API**](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API). (the Stram API is not supported by retrolambda)

In that case:

```
List<Person> newList = Stream.of(personList).filter(p -> p.getAge() > 18).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: where did p comes from inside filter(p ->..)?

Comment: in the statement `filter(p -> p.getAge() > 18)` p actually declares itself